# Sorting nested Dictionary alphabetically by sub-key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, collections, nested

Really struggling on how to sort a nested dictionary alphabetically only using its sub-keys. I cannot find an analogous question on here.

For instance I have:

```
people = {5: {'first': 'John', 'age': '27', 'last': 'Doe'},
          2: {'first': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'gender': 'Female'}}
```

But want:

```
people = {5: {'age': '27','first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe'},
          2: {'age': '22','first': 'Marie', 'gender': 'Female'}}
```

Attempt:

```
import OrderedDict from collections
for d in people:
   people[d] = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Comment: Please mention the stuff you've tried, your progress and the errors you encountered. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
import OrderedDict from collections

for data_center in dc_error_modes:
    d = dc_error_modes[data_center]
    dc_error_modes[data_center] = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))
```